# Is Spock's brain re-transplanted?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-tos, spock, chronological-order

In 2268, Spock's brain has been stolen by hostile aliens and later re-transplanted by Dr. Leonard McCoy. But 10 years earlier, Spock talks to his self from 2387 about future things and how to tackle them. In these discussions, did Spock learn about his brain being at risk or did he not?

At least, one would expect the older Spock would warn his younger alter ego to avoid removal of his brain, since Dr. Leonard McCoy ran into severe complications while finishing the surgery, so probably the whole procedure caused secondary damages to his nervous system.

Still, to my knowledge there are no historical records about such a dialog, so did Spock in fact conceal this information to his younger ego and, if so, why?

Comment: Arguably this question applies to every episode of TOS...as well as every other Star Trek canon work that Spock later appeared in. Presumably the older Spock focused on the things that he didn't already know our heros would overcome on their own (and I'm not aware of Spock actually suffering any long-term damage as a result of this episode).

Comment: Ummmm, are we talking about the changes wrought by the newest Star Trek films? Because if so, those are a separate timeline.

Comment: Spock won't need the warning because those adventures are no longer likely to happen.  Kirk got *Enterprise* way earlier in the rebooted movies than he did in the TOS timeline.